# KendoUI MVC Wrapper - Using JSONP

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I'd like to set DATATYPE of datasource's READ operation to JSONP.
It's possible with JavaScript, however I don't find if it's possible with ASP.NET MVC Wrapper.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

JSONP is auto if your using the asp.net mvc wrapper